# C# tasks are executed before Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

Why the `tasks` are executed before `Task.WhenAll`??

If you see here, from the below code snippet, first `Console.WriteLine("This should be written first..");` should be printed because I am `awaiting` the tasks beneath to it..

But if you see the output result, the `Tasks` method result is being printed before the above statement.  Ideally, the tasks method should be executed when I `await` them, but it seems that- the tasks methods are executed the moment I add them in tasks list. Why is it so?

Would you please do let me know why is this happening??

**Code:**

```
public static async Task Test()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    tasks.Add(PrintNumber(1));
    tasks.Add(PrintNumber(2));
    tasks.Add(PrintNumber(3));

    Console.WriteLine("This should be written first..");

    // This should be printed last..
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

public static async Task PrintNumber(int number)
{
    await Task.FromResult(0);

    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: No surprise your method is synchronous. Why do you expect it do behave different?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel true! I have just given a sample code snippet to understand it properly. It is NOT real time use case..

Comment: Apart from the sample being synchronous, a Task starts when you call Task.Run or whatever results in the creation of a hot task, *not* when you *wait* for it with `Task.WhenAll` or `Task.WaitAll`. If you take too long to get to `WhenAll`, the task may complete first

Comment: Tasks can run anytime after you start them, at the whim of the scheduler. In the case of an `async` method, the task starts as soon as you call the method.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _Jodrell: then what is use of Task.WhenAll? Because, someday I really want to control on execution.. which means, I want my all the tasks (in tasks list) should only run when I call Task.WhenAll

Comment: `WhenAll` means, when all of the tasks have finished.

Comment: @nunu There is seldom any reason to want tasks to start together at a specific time. If you think you do, either there is an implied dependency that should be in the code anyway (like waiting for initialization or another task to finish), or there is a misunderstanding of the scenario. You can simply call Task.Run on an array of lambdas/Actions if you really want to execute many functions at the same time, eg `var tasks=myActions.Select(act=>Task.Run(act)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you call an `async` method you get a "hot" task in return. That means that the task already started running (and maybe even completed) before you get to `await` them. That means that it's quite possible for the tasks to run and complete before the call to `Task.WhenAll`.

In your case however, while the `PrintNumber` is marked `async` it isn't asynchronous at all since you're using `Task.FromResult`. The synchronous part of an asynchronous method (which is the part until you await an asynchronous task) is always executed synchronously on the calling thread and is done before the call returns. When you use `Task.FromResult` you get a completed task so all your method is just the synchronous part and is completed before the call returns.

Comment: So, which means that- in method, which return 'Task' and in the same method, if we use 'await', it will start executing the moment call goes to 'await' ??

Comment: @nunu no, tasks start running immediatelly. `await` waits for them to finish asynchronously. If you call `HttpClient.GetAsync` the download will start immediatelly whether you call `await` or not.

Answer (score 4):

When you await a completed task (as is created by `Task.FromResult`, it completes synchronously. This means that in your example, nothing is actually happening asynchronously, which explains the order of execution.

If instead, you were to

```
await Task.Yield();
```

you'd see output more in line with your expectations.

Answer (score 3):

`Task.FromResult` won't cause yield and the task will be executed on the same thread. To achieve what you want you can do this:

```
public static async Task Test()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    tasks.Add(PrintNumber(1));
    tasks.Add(PrintNumber(2));
    tasks.Add(PrintNumber(3));

    Console.WriteLine("This should be written first..");

    // This should be printed last..
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

public static async Task PrintNumber(int number)
{
    await Task.Yield();

    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `Task` or tasks to run after something else, its easiest to write your code accordingly.

```
public static async Task Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine("This should be written first..");

    // These should be printed last..
    await Task.WhenAll(new[]
        {
            PrintNumber(1),
            PrintNumber(2),
            PrintNumber(3)
        });
}
```

---

**following on from your comment.**

So we have some functions,

```
async Task<Customer> GetRawCustomer()
{
    ...
}

async Task<string> GetCity(Customer customer)
{
    ...
}

async Task<string> GetZipCode(Customer customer)
{
    ...
}
```

We could use them like this

```
var rawCustomer = await GetRawCustomer();

var populationWork = new List<Task>();
Task<string> getCity;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawCustomer.City))
{
    getCity = GetCity(rawCustomer);
    populationWork.Add(getCity);
}

Task<string> getZipCode;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawCustomer.City))
{
    getZipCode = GetZipCode(rawCustomer);
    populationWork.Add(getZipCode);
}

...

await Task.WhenAll(populationWork);

if (getCity != null)
    rawCustomer.City = getCity.Result;

if (getZipCode != null)
    rawCustomer.ZipCode = getZipCode.Result;
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that- but consider a scenarios where I have the List<Task> and I am adding task one-by-one in my code based on certain business logic. And then, I want to execute all the tasks at the same time by Task.WhenAll

Comment: @nunu and presumably, you want something else to happen between populating the list of work and the work being done?

Comment: No, e.g. Let say that- I have customer object. Now, If Customer.City == null, then I want to retrieve the city from WebService call. Also, if Customer.ZipCode is NULL, then I want to retrieve the ZipCode from DB call. So, All the CALLS are my tasks and then I want to execute all the tasks at the same moment and based on the result of all the tasks individually, I want to fill/ compose my full Customer object.

Comment: @nunu that is very different to your question but you'll note, its not important to you when the tasks start, you want to know when they have all finished so you can aggregate the results.